# React test component with googleapi method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a method of a component that calls the google API.
My code is the next one:

```
export default class SubscribeYoutube extends Component {
state = {
    gToken: null
    /*Token obtained after login*/
}
onSubscribe() {
    axios.post('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&alt=json', {
        "snippet": {
            "resourceId":
                {
                    "channelId": "QuanticoTrends",
                    "kind": "youtube#channel"
                }
        }
    }, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": this.state.gToken
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            this.props.setComplete()
        })
        .catch(error => { })
}
render() {
    return <div>
        {this.state.gToken ?
           <button onClick={this.onSubscribe.bind(this)}>Subscribe</button> 
           :
           <GoogleLogin
                clientId="***clientId***"
                onSuccess={saveTokenInState}
                onFailure={handleError}
                isSignedIn
                tag="span"
                type=""
                scope="profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"/>}
    </div>
}
```

My problem is that i cant figure it out how to test the onSubscribe method because it makes a call to google api. Is it possible o to override that function in test environment to emulate a call to google API?

The component just renders a login button if don't have a token and a subscribe button if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the call to `axios.post()` with a stub that resolves or rejects with something defined by yourself fot that test cases. This way you can test your implementation for a failing and a successful request. Have a look at [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) that helps with mocking. Especially have a look at `stub.resolves()` and `stub.rejects()` [in the stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.4.3/stubs/).